# Android GCM RegistrationID Error

Tags: android, registration, google-cloud-messaging

I have a device that is already registered with the GCM.  I've tried searching, but I wasn't able to find any similar problems.  Most users seem to have issues getting the getRegistrationId to return a non-empty string.  Any ideas on why this causes an error?

```
public class UploadOption extends Activity{
    Intent extras = getIntent();
    String optionid = extras.getStringExtra("KEY_OPTION");
    String duration = extras.getStringExtra("KEY_DURATION");
    String reward = extras.getStringExtra("KEY_REWARD");


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.debug_layout);

        final String regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this);
        TextView tvDebug = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDebug);
        tvDebug.setText(regId);

        // Stores option id, php grabs option.
        //new Upload().execute();
    }
}
```

The error log is below:

```
01-18 18:02:51.756: D/AndroidRuntime(4478): Shutting down VM
01-18 18:02:51.756: W/dalvikvm(4478): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001e578)
01-18 18:02:51.803: E/AndroidRuntime(4478): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-18 18:02:51.803: E/AndroidRuntime(4478): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.matt.drapp/com.matt.drapp.UploadOption}: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-18 18:02:51.803: E/AndroidRuntime(4478):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1573)
01-18 18:02:51.803: E/AndroidRuntime(4478):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
01-18 18:02:51.803: E/AndroidRuntime(4478):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
01-18 18:02:51.803: E/AndroidRuntime(4478):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
01-18 18:02:51.803: E/AndroidRuntime(4478):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-18 18:02:51.803: E/AndroidRuntime(4478):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
01-18 18:02:51.803: E/AndroidRuntime(4478):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
01-18 18:02:51.803: E/AndroidRuntime(4478):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-18 18:02:51.803: E/AndroidRuntime(4478):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
01-18 18:02:51.803: E/AndroidRuntime(4478):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
01-18 18:02:51.803: E/AndroidRuntime(4478):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
01-18 18:02:51.803: E/AndroidRuntime(4478):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-18 18:02:51.803: E/AndroidRuntime(4478): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-18 18:02:51.803: E/AndroidRuntime(4478):     at com.matt.drapp.UploadOption.<init>(UploadOption.java:32)
01-18 18:02:51.803: E/AndroidRuntime(4478):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
01-18 18:02:51.803: E/AndroidRuntime(4478):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1409)
01-18 18:02:51.803: E/AndroidRuntime(4478):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
01-18 18:02:51.803: E/AndroidRuntime(4478):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1565)
01-18 18:02:51.803: E/AndroidRuntime(4478):     ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is due to the `Intent` code. Remember activity is only initialized after `onCreate()` and you are trying to get the Intent values before the activity initialize.

**Put the below code inside the `onCreate();`**

```
Intent extras = getIntent();
String optionid = extras.getStringExtra("KEY_OPTION");
String duration = extras.getStringExtra("KEY_DURATION");
String reward = extras.getStringExtra("KEY_REWARD");
```

It should work.

Comment: Thanks, that was it!  Sometimes, it just takes another pair of eyes.

Answer (score 1):

Which line in your example is causing the NullPointerException. Because if it's simply the textView not being found then that could cause the whole app to crash just because you try set the text and it's a null object.

So first, comment out the textview stuff and see if it still works. If that's not it, could you let us know which line is line 32 in your class as it is evidently not the same as on here.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your getRegistratonID is returning null. This is because you're calling it in your activity class, before you actually register with the GCM server, and receive a onRegistered callback to your GCMIntentService. If getRegistrationID returns null, you should fire off an AsyncTask to call GCMRegistrar.register.

Follow instructions [here](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html):